# Cannot enable Compute Engine API on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine

I'm having trouble enabling the Compute Engine API on my Google Cloud Platform project. I've tried enabling the API from both the Cloud Console and the gcloud command-line tool, but I keep receiving the following error message:

`Error in service 'compute.googleapis.com': The service is currently being deactivated and deactivation must complete before activation can occur.`

I've waited for a while to see if the deactivation process completes, but the issue still persists. I've also checked my IAM permissions and I have the necessary permissions to enable APIs.

The issue might have appeared after a terraform destroy, disabling the compute engine API

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can try again to enable the Compute Engine API. It became a known issue in Google Cloud Platform and a fix was rolled out.

Comment: Is there an Issue Tracker for this fix?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after 3 days it finally started working again, I didn't make any other changes in the meantime just retried from time to time to re-enable the compute APIs (via UI and CLI). It is so strange now that some of my resources have disappeared. Not too bad as I'm in a test environment but it looks scary